# Ion-checkbox does not fill the data from database

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, service, ionic3

Here I am trying to display group name with checkbox.I wanted to create privacy setting page for user, in this page I wanted to hide or show the profile information from specific users.Only the user can provide provision who can view his detail.For this task I have created groups for the different user and assign them to the users, this could be done by both user and admin.once group is assign to the user that user can see data access the get from that permission.
But my issue over here is I can't get the group name which I have bind with my checkboxes, mistry is here I can see my data in console but not on HTML and for that reason I can't go further for my development

```js
   loadGroups(fromStart: boolean) {
    var self = this;

    if (fromStart) {
      self.loading = true;
      self.groups = [];
      self.newGroups = [];

        this.dataService.getTotalGroups().then(function (snapshot) {

          self.start = snapshot.val();
          self.getGroups();
        });

    } else {
      self.getGroups();
    }
  }

  getGroups() {
    var self = this;
    let startFrom: number = self.start - self.pageSize;

    if (startFrom < 0) startFrom = 0;

      this.dataService
        .getGroupsRef()
        .once("value", function (snapshot) {
          console.log(snapshot.val());
          self.itemsService
            .reversedItems<IUserGroups>(self.mappingsService.getGroups(snapshot))
            .forEach(function (group) {

              self.groups.push(group);
            });
          self.start -= self.pageSize + 1;
          self.events.publish("groups:viewed");
          self.loading = false;
          console.log(self.groups);//i can have all data here
        });


  }
```

```html
      <ion-item no-lines>
          <ion-label>Make me discoverable by</ion-label>
          <ion-toggle color="secondary"
            [ngModel]='preferences[PREF_DISCOVERABLE]'
            (ionChange)='changePreference($event, PREF_DISCOVERABLE)' (click)='onToggleClick()'></ion-toggle>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item no-lines *ngIf="toggleClicked">

          <div *ngFor="let choice of groups">

            <ion-label>{{choice.groupName}}</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox value="choice"></ion-checkbox>
          </div>
        </ion-item>
```

data i got in my console window

```
0 :  {group_id: "-L9dQkPfCIapV6QC-ydK", groupName: "Panic", dateCreated: "2018-4-9"}
1 :  {group_id: "-L9dQhZJWTJi735VIoxh", groupName: "All", dateCreated: "2018-4-9"}
2 :  {group_id: "-L9dQcqZ_G2t1kv5_jzh", groupName: "Committee Members", dateCreated: "2018-4-9"
```

Comment: i think because the data from db is either 1 or 0, try to convert this to boolean and see

Comment: what do u mean  by data from db is either 1 or 0. Here my data what i got 0
:
{group_id: "-L9dQkPfCIapV6QC-ydK", groupName: "Panic", dateCreated: "2018-4-9"}
1
:
{group_id: "-L9dQhZJWTJi735VIoxh", groupName: "All", dateCreated: "2018-4-9"}
2
:
{group_id: "-L9dQcqZ_G2t1kv5_jzh", groupName: "Committee Members", dateCreated: "2018-4-9"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My silly mistake i had wrap label and checkbox with div which is not working i have wrap whole item into div now its working.

```
<div *ngIf="toggleClicked" >
      <ion-item *ngFor="let choice of groups" >
            <ion-label>{{choice.groupName}}</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox value="choice"></ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>
</div>
```